# Using Global.asax Begin_Request vs ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

If I want to check something per each request I can place the code in two places.

1. Placing the code in Begin_Request method in Global.asax so that the check will happen for each request
2. Creating a custom attribute and placing the checking code in OnActionExecuting method

What is the best place to do the checking? Or is there a better place to do per request checking in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you mean by checking something. But as a general answer I would say in an attribute. Why? Because it's more flexible without creating more work.
The advantage of the attribute is that you will be able to set it globally in a Global Filter collection, on a class or even on a specific method.